# How can i access one elemento of array in assembler

Tags: c, arrays, ubuntu, assembly, nasm

I need of you help... Actually, I'm working in my scholar project and I'm trying to finish it. But I don't know how to access one element of one array in assembler.

My idea is call the function assembler from C and the same time to pass the parameter. For example

```
float* calc(int n, int d, float*data){
    float* result = _mm_malloc(sizeof (float)*n*d, 16);
    calc_x86_asm(n, d, data, result)
    //Line edited, I forget to put the return
    return result; 
}
```

The function calc_x86_asm is declared in the initial of the file.

```
extern calc_x86_asm(int n, int d, float* data, float* result);
```

My function has the follow content:

```
;External asm function
extern calculate_value
section .text                   ;program
    n      equ         8
    d      equ         12
    data   equ         16
    rta    equ         20 

global calc_x86_asm    ;for linux

calc_x86_asm:
        ;Initialize a stack frame
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        pushad
.body:
        ;Load information
        mov     ebx, [ebp+rta]
        ;Initialization counters
        xor     edx, edx
.loop:
        cmp     edx, [ebp+n]            ; if(ecx < n){
        jz      .done                   ; goto .done
                                    ; else
        push    dword [ebp+d]       ; d 
        push    dword [ebp+n]       ; n
        push    dword [edx]        ; current_row
        push    dword [ebp+data]    ; data to evaluate
        call    calculate_value
        add     esp, 16             ; restore stack after to call function.
        mov     [ebx+edx*4], eax    ;<<< Here the problem
        add     edx, 1
        jmp     .loop
.done:
        .done:
        ;Pop registries
        popad
        ;Restore the call's stack frame pointer
        pop     ebp                 ; restore ebp
        ret
```

Really, I don't know if I am doing the correct form the assignation of value in memory of the array. Because When I run my project, the apps throw me on error. By the way, the calculate_value is a C function.

In C will be in this form:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    result[i] = calc(n, d, i, data);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense in the first place. Your function doesn't `return` anything even though it is declared as `float* calc(int n, int d, float*data)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have an error... I must return the result array... Thanks for your comment..

Comment: What's the prototype of the `calculate_value` C function? If it's really returning a `float` value, the return value will be on the math coprocessor stack and not `EAX`.

Comment: Thanks @pcarter, the calculate value is a float function. In this case, which register must i put to get the result???

Comment: The return value will be in the `ST0` register (the top of the math coprocessor stack). It doesn't sound like you are familiar with the coprocessor. You will need to learn how to work with it. It's way too involved to explain here. Google is your friend. If you look for the PC Assembly Language on-line book, chapter 5 covers the coprocessor.

Comment: The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has some links to ABI / calling convention docs, and to an x87 guide.  x87 is pretty much obsolete, though; in 64bit code the calling convention returns float / double in `xmm0`.  32bit code does return FP values in `ST0`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're calling a C function after carefully setting up your registers: the C function will **definitely** overwrite them. You need to save your important registers before calling the function:

```
push ebx ; Save for later
push edx ; Save for later

push    dword [ebp+d]       ; d 
push    dword [ebp+n]       ; n
push    dword [edx]        ; current_row
push    dword [ebp+data]    ; data to evaluate
call    calculate_value
add     esp, 16             ; restore stack after to call function.

pop edx ; It's later! (Note reversed restore...)
pop ebx ; It's later!
```

But this whole

- Set up your registers;
- Save them
- Call C
- Restore registers
- Go back for more

completely removes the need for using assembly in the first place: you might as well have written the whole thing in C.

Comment: You don't need to save/restore `ebx` around a call; it's already call-preserved in all normal ABIs.  Better to use call-preserved regs for both parameters in the loop, so you don't have to `push/pop` inside the loop, just at the start/end of your function.  (e.g. `ebx` and `esi` are call-preserved in all 32bit ABIs I know of)